# Copy string into struct C

Tags: c, string, struct

I have a `struct`:

```
typedef struct myStruct {
  char** a;
  char** b;
} myStruct;
```

I am trying to read from `stdin` and initialize an array of `myStruct*`

```
int main() {
  int maxlength = 60 + 1;
  int arraySize = 2;
  myStruct** myArray = (myStruct*) malloc(sizeof(myStruct*) * arraySize);
  int runningIndex = 0;
  while(1) {
    char* aline = (char*) malloc(maxlength);
    int status = getline(&aline, &maxlength, stdin);
    if(status == -1)
      break;
    char* bline = (char*) malloc(maxlength);
    getline(&bline, &maxlength, stdin);
    if(runningIndex == arraySize) {
      arraySize *= 2;
      myArray = realloc(myArray, sizeof(myStruct*) * arraySize);
    }
    myArray[runningIndex] = (myStruct*) malloc(sizeof(myStruct*));
    myArray[runningIndex]->a = &aline;
    myArray[runningIndex]->a = &bline;
    runningIndex++;
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < runningIndex; i++) {
    printf("outside the loop at index %d, a is %s and b is %s", i, *myArray[i]->a, *myArray[i]->b);
  }
}
```

I did a few `printf` within the `while` to confirm that each `myStruct` is successfully created with the strings from `stdin`. However, outside the loop, all the stored values seems to be gone. I was thinking about scope but could not figure out why. Could someone explain how I shall do this properly? Thanks!

Comment: [Do not cast the result of `malloc`.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) Where do you leave your `while` loop?

Comment: I see. Thank you for teaching me that. Sorry, edited.

Comment: source and dest == a and b ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sample to fix :

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct myStruct {
    char *a;
    char *b;
} myStruct;

int main() {
    int maxlength = 60 + 1;
    int arraySize = 2;

    myStruct* myArray = malloc(sizeof(myStruct) * arraySize);
    int runningIndex = 0;
    while(1) {
        char *aline = malloc(maxlength);
        int status = getline(&aline, &maxlength, stdin);
        if(status == -1)
            break;
        char *bline = malloc(maxlength);
        getline(&bline, &maxlength, stdin);
        if(runningIndex == arraySize) {
            arraySize *= 2;
            myArray = realloc(myArray, sizeof(myStruct) * arraySize);
        }
        myArray[runningIndex].a = aline;//&aline is address of local variable.
        myArray[runningIndex].b = bline;//And content is rewritten in each loop.
        runningIndex++;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < runningIndex; i++) {
        printf("outside the loop at index %d, a is %s and b is %s", i, myArray[i].a, myArray[i].b);
    }
    //deallocate
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A single string pointer is defined like this:

```
char *pStr;
```

An array of string pointers is defined like this:

```
char **pStrArr;
```

To dynamically create memory for a single string, do this:

```
pStr = malloc(STRING_LEN);
```

To dynamically create memory for an array of strings, do this:

```
pStrArr = (NUM_STRINGS * (*pStrArr));
for(str = 0; str < NUM_STRINGS; str++)
    pStrArr[str] = malloc(STRING_LEN);
```

In your case, you'd need to create either two `char` strings for your `struct` or two arrays of `char` strings, whatever your requirements are.  It looks like you really only need two single strings.  If so, do this:

```
typedef struct
{
    char* a;
    char* b;
} myStruct;

myStruct structure;

structure.a = malloc(STRING_LEN);
structure.b = malloc(STRING_LEN);
```

Comment: `pStrArr = (NUM_STRINGS * (*pStrArr));`?

Comment: @zoska That's equivalent to `char *` in this case.